# Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, objectanimator

here is my project:

[image: project]

animated_path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/triangle"
                 tools:targetApi="21">
    <target
        android:name="t"
        android:animation="@animator/path"/>
</animated-vector>
```

path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 300 300 L 100 300z"
        android:valueTo="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 L 200 300z"
        android:valueType="pathType"/>
</set>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.kycq.reader">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LoadingActivity.java:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
    }
}
```

activity_loading.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kycq.reader.LoadingActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kycq.reader"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // enable vectorDrawable
        vectorDrawables.setUseSupportLibrary(true)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // use 23.2.0
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

why i receive the error when use 'animated-vector' at android studio 2.0 beta?

[image: error]

the unbelievable is when i delete 'res/animator' and 'animated_path.xml',then rebuild project,it works.

it make me crazy, i don't know why,and how to solve the problem,anyone can help me ?

the terrible is,sometime it throw the error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kycq.reader/com.kycq.reader.LoadingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

but i had set the style 'ActivityTheme' to the LoadingActivity.

now i post the project to the web:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7cSTEJuaMZBLW9VYWM5X0szVlk

Comment: What is the content of your `onCreate()`?

Comment: nothing,just setContentView().it throw error at setContentView()

Comment: Could you post the `.zip` project so We could reproduce the error?

Comment: if setContentView is causing the error, can you post your onCreate method and the layout you are loading?

Comment: ok,i post the code and the new error.

Comment: @csx Whats happens if you set `buildToolsVersion "23.2.0"` in your build.gradle?

Comment: the following packages are not available..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7cSTEJuaMZBLW9VYWM5X0szVlk

Comment: i ran you code in my system and its worked properly without  any error

Answer (score 7):

also try "clean project"
this occurred to me even if no changes made to build version or manifest.

`"Android Studio: menu> Build -> Clean Project"`
did it.

if this doesn't solve your problem, also try
`"Android Studio: menu> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"`

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue this morning. How I fix it:

1. Remove application level attribute from your android manifest file  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.
2. Add activity level attribute instead like so:

   ```
   [Activity(MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
   ```

Comment: this works, however the preferred/normal android way of doing this is to add the theme in the manifest: `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">...`

Answer (score 1):

'Rebuild Project' solved the problem for my project on Android Studio 2020.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when your `buildToolsVersion` is not updated to match the version of `playservices` and other dependencies

Check here for the latest version:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did these steps, and after them it worked:

- Reinstall Android Studio
- Build -> Clean Project
- File -> Invalidate Caches
- And Updating gradle (there was a popup bottom right)