# Unable to start activity crash decorcontent parent

Tags: java, android

Unable to start activity Component Info ERROR

When im starting my app, its skippp all the ativity and goes at the somewhere activity and after 3 seconds it finally crashes.

its show no visible error on my java and xml...

im having error on my logcat

idont know where is the error

```
2019-10-16 05:55:20.542 23865-23865/com.ilsproj.ilovebatangas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ilsproj.ilovebatangas, PID: 23865
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ilsproj.ilovebatangas/com.ilsproj.ilovebatangas.ui.CategorySelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)' on a null object reference
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:753)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.ilsproj.ilovebatangas.ui.CategorySelection.onCreate(CategorySelection.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7042)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Heres my Splashcreen.java

```
public class Splashsrcreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashsrcreen);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(Splashsrcreen.this,CategorySelection.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

My catergoryselection.java

```
public class CategorySelection extends AppCompatActivity {
CardView imagebutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_selection);

    CardView mountain = findViewById(R.id.cv_mountains);
    mountain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( CategorySelection.this, Cat_Mountains.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_category_selection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:layout_width="385dp"
                android:layout_height="589dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:rowCount="5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53999996">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_beaches"
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="155dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffff"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/beaches" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Beaches"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_mountains"
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="155dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffff"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/mountain" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Mountains"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_island"
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="155dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffff"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/island" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Island"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_churces"
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="155dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffff"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/churches" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Churches"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_heritage"
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="155dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:background="#ffff"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/heritage" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Heritage"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            </GridLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: "at com.ilsproj.ilovebatangas.ui.CategorySelection.onCreate(CategorySelection.java:20)" This part gives the clue where to start looking. What is is line 20 in `CategorySelection.java`?

Comment: Also, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945052/attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-void-android-support-v7-widget-decorcontentp) will help

Comment: line 20 is: setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_selection);

Comment: I try your activity_category_selection.xml it's working fine. Try cleaning your project and try posting your dependencies here.

Comment: L2_Paver tried your xml and it's working fine. So next what you can do close your project and import it again. Your IDE may not find that layout.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a caching problem.
try with:
`"Android Studio: menu> Build -> Clean Project"`
or
`"Android Studio: menu> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"`